# eclipse　Androidアプリケーションプロジェクト　エクスポートについて

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-service

`google maps android api v2` と　`google　play　services_lib`を使用して
Googleマップを表示させるアプリをエクスポートしたのですが、これをインポートした際に
`google　play　services_lib`を参照することが出来なくなっていました。

もう一度、同じようなアプリをエクスポートして、他のパソコンでインポートさせようと思っているのですが、
どうすれば移した後にエラーをさせずに使用できるようになるでしょうか？

**追記**
`google　play　services_lib`のパスの設定をした後にもエラーが出ていたのですが、Eclipseを再起動したら大丈夫そうでした。ありがとうございました。

ですが、srcの中にsnippetというものが出来ているようです。これがエラーを出していて、もともと無かったと思うのですが、消してもいいのですか？

Answer (score 1):

`Google Maps Android API v2`は、`Google Play Services`の一部として提供されています。

これは`Google Maps`の機能が増えたときなど、Android SDK自体をアップデートしなくとも、`Google Play Services`ライブラリ側のみのバージョンを上げて新しい機能にアクセスできるようにするためです。

昔は`jar`が利用していましたが、現在ではライブラリプロジェクトとして提供されています。

ライブラリプロジェクトへの参照・更新の方法は、[Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)に記載されています。

再インポートしたときに参照されなくなってしまったのは、アプリのプロジェクトから、`Google Play Services`ライブラリプロジェクトへのパスが相対パスで指定されているためだと思われますので、正しいパスに修正すれば問題ないと思います。

新しいPCで参照するには、最初にプロジェクトを作成したときと同様に、先にEclipseへ`Google Play Services`ライブラリプロジェクトをインポートする必要があります。